# ios development: awakefromnib called every time viewcontroller appears

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

Some background at first: I'm developing storyboard based application (ios7) where UITabbarController is the root controller. One of the tabs contain navigation controller. Viewcontroller embedded to that navigationcontroller has button, which opens new viewcontroller when pressed. I'm using push segue to do that.

My issue is following: Every time I press the button and new viewcontroller opens, awakefromnib is always called. I'm trying to do some initializing in the awakefromnib function, but now it is not possible because the function is called always when the  viewcontroller appears.

Any help with this?

Comment: What initialisation do you need to do? What needs to be available for it to work?

Comment: You create a new view controller and load it from the nib (in the storyboard) every time you press the button -- so it *should* call awakeFromNib on that new view controller.  What is happening is what should happen.  What else were you expecting?

Comment: Oh, I just though that it calls this awakeFromNib only once, when user opens the view the first time. Basically, my view is tableview, which loads its data from webserver on startup. Maybe I'll try to find some other way to implement this feature. Thanks for help.